# What's the use of defining ARGS in a different header file?

Tags: c, coding-style

So I've been going through some code, and there's some things I can't understand.
I have two header files. One is called 'args.h' and in that there are these statements, amongst others:

```
#if (defined(__cplusplus) || defined(__STDC__) || defined(c_plusplus))
#define NEW_STYLE 1
#define VOID    void
#define ARGS(parenthesized_list) parenthesized_list
#else
#define NEW_STYLE 0
#define VOID
#define ARGS(parenthesized_list) ()
#define const
#endif

#if !defined(EXIT_SUCCESS)
#define EXIT_SUCCESS    0
#define EXIT_FAILURE    1
#endif
```

In the other header file, function prototypes are declared like this:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void     yyerror ARGS((const char *s_));
extern int      yylex ARGS((void));
extern int      yyparse ARGS((void));
extern int      yywrap ARGS((void));

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

and a bunch of other stuff.

So my questions are:

1> What exactly does #define const do?

2> Why is arg declared in the other header file? Couldn't we simply declare the functions like a normal extern void a(const char *s__)? Or is this simply a preference of style?

Thanks.

Comment: ouch I hope `const` gets `#undef`ed after that.

Comment: I would immediately think that the args might be being used elsewhere, and the file was separate for dependency reasons. Either way, it must be a special case if you have families of functions with the same parameter list. Can you give real examples?

Comment: Yes, it is undefined later. The specific case I'm referring to is for a lex file where these two files were used as headers  to the lex file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to allow the code to compile with a pre-standard C compiler. It turns a function prototype into a function declaration, and simply removes `const` completely.

If you need to use a compiler so ancient that it doesn't understand prototypes or `const`, you have little choice but to use something like this. Otherwise, you're generally best off eliminating these horrible kludges.

20 years ago, code like this was common and necessary. It seems harder to excuse today, but I suppose there may still be a few platforms for which a reasonably modern compiler isn't available.

Comment: "code like this was common" was it so common that wasn't even worth a comment, or at least `#ifndef __STDC_VERSION__`? Or can we safely say that the author is a hooligan? ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: It was common enough that I'd expect almost anybody who wrote C at the time to recognize it pretty easily. Rather that "hooligan" he may have been pretty progressive, adding `const` and prototypes to code that previously lacked them completely. `__STDC_VERSION__` was undependable at the time.

Comment: I'd definitely want ARGS to be defined "properly" somewhere, so that I can have prototypes on compilers that do support them, then choose which version to #define at config time. So I'm slightly surprised there's nothing in the file explaining how ARGS is actually supposed to work - if it expands to `()` in all builds and compilers then you may as well not bother specifying the parameter list ever.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: at least in most cases, it was defined "properly" somewhere or other, but that definition depended on (frequently arcane, indecipherable) figuring out the compiler/version in use. Since the code *compiles* this way, people naively porting the code to a new compiler may easily strip out the compiler detection and just leave this.

Comment: I doubt the author was a hooligan, he's pretty well known :) My fault for not posting the full file and the context of the header file. I'll do that now.

Comment: @Jerry: ah, I see. I've always been a big fan of porting headers -- ask a human being to answer such arcane questions. Although that might just be because I fear and distrust `autoconf`.

Answer (score 0):

That are tweaks to make the code portable among compilers lacking this or that feature

1. is removing const everywhere (for sure not a good idea if you have a modern compiler)
2. this has to do with the [ANSI C Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C)